# present simple or present continuous when describing a picture?

Tags: tense

When describing how someone is dressed in a picture, should one use the present simple or the present continuous? For example:

> Charlie **wears** blue pyjamas.
>
> Charlie **is wearing** blue pyjamas.

Which is better?

Answer (score 2):

Native speakers would use the present continuous:

> Charlie **is wearing** blue pyjamas.

I suppose the sentiment is of an ongoing moment captured in time.

Side note:  The American spelling is *pajamas*.